# How to deploy my RESTful application to Apache server?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, rest, jersey

I built my java RESTful application in Eclipse with Jersey and a couple other libraries. My question is, how do I deploy this to a Tomcat server? Do I export it as a WAR file? Do I need to deploy the libraries I used as well or are they packaged in the WAR file?
The server is running on an ubuntu machine which I can access over ssh. I got the server running with "apt-get install tomcat7". Which folder should I put it in? Is any configuration needed? What should I do with the web.xml file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually wouldn't use Apache to directly serve a Jersey web application as Apache is not a Java application server. It would be served from a Java server such as [Tomcat](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CD4QFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftomcat.apache.org%2F&ei=UsM7VfvgDMzcati7gagF&usg=AFQjCNGNDNjXeRgE3wbwAp7qKd_whu88YQ&sig2=IeBnPfc76O6nEd03AB6kTA&bvm=bv.91665533,d.ZWU) instead. If you wish to serve your Jersey application as if it was located on your Apache server, you would still have a Tomcat server running and [set up a reverse proxy to your Tomcat server](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy). I personally use a server such as [Wildfly](http://wildfly.org/) or [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) which implements the full JavaEE profile and means you are less likely to run into errors. Nearly all Java application servers also have the capability of serving static content so unless you specifically need Apache features, you do not need to go to the trouble of also running Apache.

With each one of these servers you would need the .WAR file and deploy it, either through the appropriate maven plugin, the web manager or placing the .WAR into the appropriate directory.

Dependencies for a .WAR specified in the 'compile' scope will be included as part of the .WAR file and those in the 'provided' scope will not be included (for when your web server has these included)

Comment: Just a few seconds ago I uninstalled apache and replaced it for tomcat7. So I only need the WAR file?

Comment: Yep, you would place it in your Tomcat webapps folder and Tomcat will extract it and enable it, should be accessed through http://localhost:8080/your-app-name when you add your-app-name.war. If you want to deploy it to the root directory, call it ROOT.war